# multiple div boxes with images with one class. Only fade one image at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

I have a problem with my javascript.

I am trying to create a javascript that fades away a white/black png file when you hover over the `div`.
But the problem is that I have several `divs` and `images`, and one `class`.

How can I get this to work?

Put it all in a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/auURQ/61/

All help is very appreciated :-)

```
<div class="aBlock first">
<div class="eTop">
    <img src="http://www.designduck.dk/portfolio/img/project1.jpg" alt="project1">
    <img class="overlay" src="http://www.designduck.dk/portfolio/img/white.png" width="360" height="135" alt="whitebox">
    <img style="margin-left:43px;;margin-top:35px;" src="http://www.designduck.dk/portfolio/img/wordpress.png" width="270" height="60" alt="wordpress">
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".overlay").show();
$('.eTop').hover(

function () {
    $('.overlay').fadeOut('slow');
},

function () {
    $('.overlay').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

});

Comment: I dont exactly understand the problem. Both of your eTop divs are overlapping in the fiddle so whenever you hover over either of them, the image fades in. That's not what you want?

Comment: Overlapping???

I want only one to fade at a time when you hover.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want the fading to happen to the `.eTop` that you are hovering over?

Comment: Yea, I want the fade to happen when you hover the `.eTop`  div.
But only one box at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it right, you want the animation to appear only to image that is currently hovered. For this you need to add following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".overlay").show();
$('.eTop').hover(

function () {
    $(this).children('.overlay').fadeOut('slow'); // selects element with class     .overlay that is direct child of div that is currently hovered
},

function () {
    $(this).children('.overlay').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

Here is updated jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/auURQ/71/

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this) first to spot the specific div.eTop and then find the contained image.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".overlay").show();
    $('.eTop').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut('slow');
    },

    function () {
       $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```